# classes for a-tag do not work in ck_editor since TYPO3 8.7.12

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x

in TYPO3 8.7.12 this configuration in the yaml file of my ck_editor works:

```
    stylesSet:
  - { name: "Konfigurator-Button", element: "a", attributes: { 'class': 'button konfigurator--button button--table' } }
```

after upgrading to TYPO3 8.7.25 oder 8.7.26 it does not work anymore. Other stiles do work, only for the a-tag they do not.

Are there any breaking changes in the last upgrades?

Thanks!

Comment: I suspect this is related to the issue with multiple classes (https://forge.typo3.org/issues/86852). 'Does not work' means your stylesSet for anchors isn't showing in the RTE dropdown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution - well: a work around ...

In newer 8.7-versions of TYPO3 it seems not possible to define a stylesSet for the a tag with more than one classes anymore.

This don`t work:

```
stylesSet:
- { name: "Konfigurator-Button", element: "a", attributes: { 'class': 'button konfigurator--button button--table' } }
```

but this will work:

```
stylesSet:
- { name: "Konfigurator-Button", element: "a", attributes: { 'class': 'myspecialbutton' } }
```

for other Tags it is possible to use more than one class but not for the a tag. I can live with it.